# Unable to fix UnknownHostException while reading a csv file from a HDFS dir

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

My spark program is running on a server: `serverA`. I am running the code from pyspark terminal. Using that program, I am trying to read a csv file from another cluster set up on another server -> server: `serverB`, HDFS cluster: `clusterB` as below:

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').appName("Detector").config('spark.app.name','dummy_App').config('spark.executor.memory','2g').config('spark.executor.cores','2').config('spark.yarn.keytab','/home/testuser/testuser.keytab').config('spark.yarn.principal','krbtgt/HADOOP.NAME.COM@NAME.COM').config('spark.executor.instances','1').config('hadoop.security.authentication','kerberos').config('spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems','hdfs://clusterB').config('spark.yarn.principal','testuser@NAME.COM').getOrCreate()
```

The file I am trying to read is on cluster: `clusterB` as below:

```
(base) testuser@hdptetl:[~] {46} $ hadoop fs -df -h
Filesystem          Size     Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://clusterB  787.3 T  554.5 T    230.7 T   70%
```

The keytab details (path of keytab, KDC REALM) I mentioned in the spark configuration is present on the server `serverB`
When I try to load the file as:

```
csv_df = spark.read.format('csv').load('hdfs://botest01/test/mr/wc.txt')
```

The code results in `UnknownHostException` as below:

```
>>> tdf = spark.read.format('csv').load('hdfs://clusterB/test/mr/wc.txt')
20/07/15 15:40:36 WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'java.net.UnknownHostException: clusterB'
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I did here and how can I fix it ?

Comment: try to use IP instead of name

Comment: Got it and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the above comment, I used IP address everywhere.